# java, verify XLSX file contain Macro(using poi)

Tags: java

I have a job for verify XLSX excel have or not macro code .I used method blow.

exception below:

```
       "org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException': The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

pls open below link:
https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-if-xls-excel-file-contains-a-macro.html

Answer (score 0):

xlsx type is macro-free workbooks, excel have an extra type called macro-enabled under extension xlsm.